# Determining if all polynomials of the form $a_{0}+a_{1}x$ is a subspace of $P_{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

As the titles states I have to determine weather or not polynomials of the form $a_{0}+a_{1}x$ is a subspace of $P_{3}$, the polynomials of the form $a_{0}+a_{1}x$ have $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ as real numbers.

So since the polynomial is of the third degree, the entire polynomial would look like:

$a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+a_{3}x^3$

and the crux(I assume) is that I can pick any numbers for  $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ to prove the that this is indeed a subspace of $P_{3}$.

Since subspaces with polynomials are equivocally described in my book, I would like to know when testing the axiom  "closure under addition" for   verifying if this polynimal is a subspace of $P_{3}$

adding two polynomials:

$(a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+a_{3}x^3) +  (b_{0}+b_{1}x+b_{2}x^2+b_{3}x^3$)

I could substitute:

$a_{0} =1 $  $b_{0} =1$ and   $a_{1} = 2$  $ b_{1} = -2$

Meaning that I would get:

\begin{align}(1+2x+a_{2}x^2+a_{3}x^3) +  (1-2x+b_{2}x^2+b_{3}x^3)
=(1+1) +(b_{2}+a_{2})x^2+(b_{2}+a_{2})x^3  \end{align}

Would this still be considered to be the subspace of $P_{3}$ even though the polynomial have't retained it's full length, however it has kept the same degree?

Help would be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

Step $1$: check that $Q=\{a_0+a_1x | a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subset of $P_3$.

This is true since we can write $a_0+a_1x=a_0+a_1x+0x^2+0x^3$.

Step $2$: check closure under addition:

$$(a_0 + a_1 x )+(b_0+b_1)x=(a_0+a_1)+(a_1+b_1)x$$

Note that $a_0+a_1, b_0+b_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

- I will leave checking of closure under scalar multiplication as an exercise.
- Remark: you have to work with general entries rather than specific examples.

Comment: Regarding "working with general entries", usually I would. But why specify that $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$  are real numbers? Usually they omit to mention that the constants are real numbers.

Comment: oh, I usually specify what objects I am working on. If $P_3 = \{ a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3|a_0, a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ but we have $R_1 = \{ a_0+a_1x| a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb{C}\}$ then $R_1$ is not a subset and hence can't be a subspace.

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia $a_0$ and $a_1$ are *arbitrary* real numbers.  This means that they can be any real value you like.  Once you fix them (as you have done) you are working with a *specific example*, and no longer working with general entries.  We specify that they are real to distinguish them from, say, complex or $p$-adic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To test closure under addition, you want to already start with polynomials in the alleged subspace. For example,
$$(a_0+a_1x)+(b_0+b_1x)=(a_0+b_0)+(a_1+b_1)x$$
This is still in the same form (meaning it has no higher degree terms), so the subset is indeed closed under addition.

Comment: I might having issues interpeting the exercise. If understand it correctly the form $a_{0}+a_{1}x$ is still a part of the the longer polynomial(of third  the degree) however, since they are interested in of the form  $a_{0}+a_{1}x$  it is only pertinent for me to test $a_{0}+a_{1}x$ against the axiom for closure under addition?

Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: @Al You only care about what happens when you add two elements of the subspace. For it to be closed under addition, you need to be able to add two elements of the subspace and get something that is still in the subspace. Elements outside the subspace are of no consequence (as long as the sum isn't).